# How to update null data fields to match another columns data field?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with a 'user_id' column. Within that same table I have another data field labeled 'GMID'. Within that GMID column there are some fields that are null, the ones that aren't null have values that match the user_id data field within that row. Is there a way to create a script or query that will update all null fields in the GMID column to match the corresponding data values in the user_id row within that row? Are there any best practices I should follow, different approaches? Thanks in advance for anyone that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is

```
UPDATE your_table
SET GMID=user_id
WHERE GMID IS NULL
```

But you even don't need WHERE if GMID  always should be same as user_id.

By the way, why do you need two columns with same data in one table?

Comment: Thanks! We have some pending design changes so our team may change the method in which we go about this. Lastly, to answer your question, our team is currently doing some data migration and my mentor wants me to update the fields in this table as well as any other tables where GMID occurs. So I suppose it isn't just one table. Also, Is there any advice you can offer if I wanted to update every instance of GMID to match user_id in every table? Sorry if this isn't clear. I'm still learning :).. Also, Will this query update every GMID to match the  unique corresponding user_id in that row?

Comment: This query will update all empty `GMID`. It will place value from `user_id` column from that raw to column `GMID`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be using the 'coalesce' function. It will return the first non-null value. This approach does not involve data changes on your table.  On a query you can 'select coalesce(GMID, user_id) as GMID ...' it will return the first column that is not null.

Documentation for oracle DB:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm

Update: I just reversed the name of the columns inside the coalesce function...